# Javascript html string concatenation Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know what I am missing here? Aparently, the error come from **show_more('+ link +')**   Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```js
    function show_more(mylink) {
        console.log(mylink);
        alert(mylink);
    }
```

```js
function getImages(index, stop) {
    var html = "";
    currentIndex += stop;
    // create the img tags.
    for (var i = index; i < index + stop; i++) {
      var link = "http://31stbridge.com/godson_project/uploads/" + images[i].photo_url;
       html += '<div class="grid-item"><a href="#" onclick="show_more('+ link +')"><img src="http://baseurl/path/' + images[i].photo_url + '"></a><div class = "subtitle" align="center"> <h1>' + images[i].photo_group + '</h1><form><button class="downloadbut" formaction="' + images[i].zip + '"></button></form></div></div>';
    }
    var str = $(html);
    grid.append(str);
    grid.masonry("appended", str);
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to avoid using inline event handlers.

Comment: You are missing quotes around the `url` parameter for `show_more`. But @undefined is also correct - you can avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a missing double quote. You have:

```
html += '... onclick="show_more('+ link +')">...'
```

You have a global string in single quotes, in which you define the value of attribute 'onclick' in double quotes, into which you will have the value of your link, raw, between your round brackets.

You should add -quotes- escaped single quotes:

```
html += '... onclick="show_more(\''+ link +'\')">...'
```

Comment: thank Saucistophe, but I got (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: show_more is not defined

Comment: Then you need to ensure that your function definition is accessible to your listener. Since yoou edit your HTML directly, you need to make sure that show_more is accessible to the global scope.
You can do that by opening your browser's dev tools, and in the console, type in *window.show_more*. If you get "undefined", then you have your error.

Comment: my bad.. you were right, I have somehow mis-typed the function name. the escape single quote resolved the issue.

Comment: @AbbeyOla did you try the template string approach, it has been updated and should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use template string, will make string formation much more simple and easy. Take a look at below snippet.

In current code, some quotes are missing show_more("'+ link +'") try avoid this approach altogether.

```js
function getImages(index, stop) {
  var html = "";
  currentIndex += stop;
  // create the img tags.
  for (var i = index; i < index + stop; i++) {
    var link = "http://31stbridge.com/godson_project/uploads/" + images[i].photo_url;
    html += `<div class="grid-item"><a href="#" onclick="show_more('${link}')"><img src="http://baseurl/path/${images[i].photo_url}"></a><div class = "subtitle" align="center"> <h1>${images[i].photo_group}</h1><form><button class="downloadbut" formaction="${images[i].zip}"></button></form></div></div>`;
  }
  var str = $(html);
  grid.append(str);
  grid.masonry("appended", str);
}
});
```

Creating a dummy snippet below to demonstrate it is working.

```js
function show_more(mylink) {
  console.log('a')
  console.log(mylink);
}

function dummyGetImages() {

  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += `<div class="grid-item"><a href="#" onclick="show_more('${"123"}')"><img src="http://baseurl/path/${"url"}" alt="click here to see it works"/></a><div class = "subtitle" align="center"> <h1>${"group"}</h1><form><button class="downloadbut" formaction="${"action"}"></button></form></div></div>`;
}

dummyGetImages();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: thanks Shubham .. but I get same error with your code. what exactly did you add or remove from mine?

Comment: I have removed string concatenation  entirely and used template string. See of I have missed some paranthesis here or there. But this is how you should create strings when lots of var are involved. Check what string is being formed and if it has quotes around the link.

Comment: @AbbeyOla what we missed was quotes,  earlier it was "show_more(${link})" but it should be "show_more("${link}")". Updated the answer check if this works now.

Comment: @AbbeyOla added working snippet. Sorry for trouble "show_more('${link}')" replace the double quote around link to single quote. Updated your function code block as well.

Answer (score 0):

Extra brackets at the end gives you unexpected error in the console

```js
function getImages(index, stop) {
    var html = "";
    currentIndex += stop;
    // create the img tags.
    for (var i = index; i < index + stop; i++) {
      var link = "http://31stbridge.com/godson_project/uploads/" + images[i].photo_url;
       html += '<div class="grid-item"><a href="#" onclick="show_more("'+ link +'")"><img src="http://baseurl/path/' + images[i].photo_url + '"></a><div class = "subtitle" align="center"> <h1>' + images[i].photo_group + '</h1><form><button class="downloadbut" formaction="' + images[i].zip + '"></button></form></div></div>';
    }
    var str = $(html);
    grid.append(str);
    grid.masonry("appended", str);
  }
```

Comment: The call to `show_more` is still incorrect in the inline handler.

Comment: yes, I can confirm @vlaz is correct ... the error persist

Comment: no @MonicaAcha , this doesnt work ... the variable 'link' was translated as string in your new answer and I got the following error.  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: Have a look at the edited code. You can also use escape characters to avoid confusions.